# Prove with sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

$(a_n)^{\infty}_{n=0}$ is a sequence that define by 
$$a_n=\begin{cases}\frac{n}{2} & \mathrm{if}  & n=2k\\\frac{n-1}{2} & \mathrm{if}& n=2k+1\end{cases}$$
suppose $S(n)=a_0+a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n \\n\geq 1\\$
If $x,y \in \mathbb{N},$ prove that $$\forall x>y :xy=S(x+y)-S(x-y)$$
It seems to be an easy  problem , but I am stuck on this. I am thankful for a Hint or solution guide . Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First we calculate $$S(n+2y)-S(n)=a_{n+1} + a_{n+2} +...+ a_{n+2y}$$ 
And note that   $$a_{n+1} + a_{n+2}=n+1, ~~a_{n+3} + a_{n+4} =n+3,~~... $$

So $$S(n+2y)-S(n)=n+1 + n+3 + n+5....+n+2y-1  ~ = ny+y^{2}$$

Now plugging  $n=x-y$  in both sides we get $$xy=S(x+y)-S(x-y)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint, $a_n + a_{n+1} = \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n+1-1}{2} = n$.

Comment: This is a good though pretty scarce hint. I can't understand why it was downvoted...